# jnetpcap library unable to build on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, jnetpcap

I am trying to install JNetPcap and followed the instructions given at [here](http://jnetpcap.com/compile/debian). At step 12, I am unable to run the ant command and i see the error

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java
```

As I am able to run Java classes from eclipse or from command line I don't think if it's a problem with `JAVA_HOME`.

echo $PATH shows

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin

Kindly let me know if am missing something here.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither running `java` from the command line or running `eclipse` will require `JAVA_HOME` to be set.  However, the build procedure you are trying to use `ant`, and `ant` *often does* require `JAVA_HOME` to be set appropriately.  (It actually depends on the version of `ant` that you are using.  The use of `JAVA_HOME` is typically in the wrapper script for `ant`.)

Just set it.

JAVA_HOME should probably be set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun` ... based on what you gave said `PATH` to.

However, it is also possible that the problem is that your `PATH` is incorrect.  Or that you have (somehow) managed to get the owner/group/permissions on your Java install incorrect, such that the `java` command isn't executable.

1. Check that running `java -version` displays the installed Java version.
2. Repeat with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -version`.

Comment: thanks for reply Stephen but my echo $JAVA_HOME shows the correct path /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun. Propbably i should have added it in my post.

Comment: Did you try the other things that I suggested?

Comment: If you were unable to run "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -version", that means that what you have in your PATH is incorrect; i.e. "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun" is not the correct path to your Java installation.  You should start by correcting PATH and JAVA_PATH to use the correct path.